# Cross sections of two surfaces in Civil 3D

Tags: profile, civil3d

In Civil 3D I have calculated the volume between two surfaces. I would like to have corresponding cross sections of the first and second surface for all the study area.
"Create superimposed profile" cannot solve the problem completely since it creates only profiles along one alignment and doesn't cover entire study area.
I have did it in Land but I could not find the tools in Civil 3D.

Any suggestion.

Comment: You need to describe your question clearer. A profile would only be capable of depicting points (possibly original and proposed)along a line. It would require multiple profiles to cover an entire surface

Comment: @BradNesom, Completely, you are right. Let's say I am looking for cross sections in study area which present both surfaces in each section.

Comment: Can you edit your question to be clearer. for instance the "Besides" statement either means you don't want the previous or you want something besides cross section of first and second surface? maybe you mean "also" you want...

Comment: @BradNesom, Done. Any technical idea about the question?

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly versed in displaying both the surface and the cut/fill surface in your section data.But I know it can be done.
Here are some of the tutorial/help folders for civil3d.
Have you used them?

> Assemblies folder Windows XP:
>   C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Autodesk\C3D 2011\enu\Assemblies\
>   Windows Vista:
>   C:\ProgramData\Autodesk\C3D 2011\enu\Assemblies\
>   Windows 7:
>   C:\ProgramData\Autodesk\C3D 2011\enu\Assemblies\
>
> Autodesk Documents folder
>   Windows XP:
>   C:\Documents and Settings[user name]\My Documents\Autodesk
>   Windows Vista:
>   C:\Users[user name]\Documents\Autodesk
>   Windows 7:
>   C:\Users[user name]\Documents\Autodesk
>
> Civil 3D Project Templates folder
>   C:\Civil 3D Project Templates
>
> Civil 3D Projects folder
>   C:\Civil 3D Projects
>
> Data folder
>   Windows XP:
>   C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Autodesk\C3D 2011\enu\Data\
>   Windows Vista:
>   C:\ProgramData\Autodesk\C3D 2011\enu\Data\
>   Windows 7:
>   C:\ProgramData\Autodesk\ C3D2011\enu\Data\
>
> Local Template folder
>   Windows XP:
>   C:\Documents and Settings[user name]\Local Settings\Application Data\Autodesk\C3D 2011\enu\Template\
>   Windows Vista:
>   C:\Users[user name]\AppData\Local\Autodesk\C3D 2011\enu\Template\
>   Windows 7:
>   C:\Users[user name]\AppData\Local\Autodesk\C3D 2011\enu\Template\
>
> My Civil Tutorial Data folder
>   If this folder does not already exist, create it at the following location to save the tutorial drawings as you work on them:
>   Windows XP:
>   C:\Documents and Settings[user name]\My Documents\Autodesk
>   Windows Vista:
>   C:\Users[user name]\Documents\Autodesk
>   Windows 7:
>   C:\Users[user name]\My Documents\Autodesk
>
> tutorial drawings folder
>   "AutoCAD Civil 3D installation location"\Help\Civil Tutorials\Drawings
>   tutorial folder
>   "AutoCAD Civil 3D installation location"\Help\Civil Tutorials